# Auto-download cause loading error in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

Can, anyone, please, assist in following:

Has a page which when visited, automatically downloads .vcf (business card of chosen user). And that is working correctly.

[image]

**Note: Download starts automatically, without any code/user interraction**

The problem is, that Cypress hangs and finally throws error without asserting any element on page.

**Important: Test does not change domain - cross-origin is not reason for that hanging. It just change page:**

```
Start page: https://example.com/login
Card page: https://example.com/bc/{BCId}
```

Code which used to visit page:

```
     let urlCard = Cypress.config().baseUrl + '/bc/' + cardNew;
     cy.visit(urlCard);
     cy.wait(5000);
```

Result is, error and it never check elements on opened page.

Check screenshots below - cy.visit step & error thrown

[image]

[image]

Is there some way to avoid this error and finish test?

Thank you in advance

Network tab:

[image]

Comment: Did you try increasing pageLoadTimeout as suggested in the last screen?

Comment: @Fody Did, that, but does not change anything - error is thrown

Comment: Check the Network tab for anything (apart from say icons) that fails. I had the same problem when a POST from the app was blocked - result was page load event not firing.

Comment: @Fody Not a single request fails. Just checked. Added screenshot in question body